# Laravel QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to run the following Query with Query builder.

```
$products = \DB::table('users')
            ->join('products','products.auth_id','users.id')
            ->leftjoin('buys','products.id','buys.product_id')
            ->select('products.*','users.avatar',DB::raw('COUNT(buys.product_id) as total_sells') ) 
            ->groupBy('products.id')               
            ->where('products.status','=','1')
            ->take(20)
            ->paginate(4);

Where in products.id could be there in buys table or not..
```

But i was getting following Error.
I changed the `database.php mysql array from strict = true to false`.

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'cart.products.name' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Comment: Try to put your ```groupBy``` at the end of the query. **Edit**: after the ```where```

Comment: I tried same Error I'm getting

Comment: Oh yeah, your ```groupBy``` needs to specify every column that you're selecting (no aggregation). So basically every column from ```products``` and ```users.avatar```.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$products = \DB::table('users')
->selectRaw('products.*,users.avatar, COUNT(buys.product_id) as total_sells') 
->where('products.status','=','1')
        ->join('products','products.auth_id','=', 'users.id')
        ->leftjoin('buys','products.id','buys.product_id')
        ->groupBy('products.id')                    
        ->take(20)
        ->get();
```

I'm not sure if paginate will work will query builder.

Comment: oh forget to modify 
->leftjoin('buys','products.id','=', 'buys.product_id')

Comment: I tried with that also..though i didn't added carts table  with that..but didn't getting exact output.. it's showing `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'cart.products.name' isn't in GROUP BY`